# Databricks Init Script not able to run a tar file from DBFS

Tags: shell, sh, databricks, cluster-computing, workspace

I am trying to run the below code as init script in Databricks workspace but it is failing to run the tar command on the .tgz file and errors out as

"tar (child): /dbfs/FileStore/scipoptsuite_8_0_3.tgz\r: Cannot open: Invalid argument

tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now"

```
#!/bin/bash

tar xvzf /dbfs/FileStore/scipoptsuite_8_0_3.tgz
cd scipoptsuite-8.0.3
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DAUTOBUILD=on
make
make check
make install

export SCIPOPTDIR=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

pip install pyscipopt

cp /usr/local/lib/libscip.so.8.0 /lib
cp /usr/local/lib/libscip.so.8.0 /usr/lib
cp /usr/local/lib/libscip.so.8.0.3.0 /lib
cp /usr/local/lib/libscip.so.8.0.3.0 /usr/lib

pip install tqdm
pip install azure.identity
pip install azure.storage.blob
pip install openpyxl
```

I tried to change the syntax in the tar command like
tar xvzf dbfs:/FileStore/scipoptsuite_8_0_3.tgz
but it failed with the error "tar (child): Cannot connect to dbfs: resolve failed"